# Is it suitable to use usleep as Timer in c

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads

I am doing C program in Linux . I have a main thread which continuously updates values of two variables and other thread write those variable values into a file every 20 milliseconds. I have used usleep to achieve this time interval.  sample code is below.

```
 main()
{
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

 pthread_create(...write_file..);   /* started another thread by passing   a  function write_file */
 while(variable1) 
  {
    updates value of variables 

  }

return 0;
}


void write_file()

{
 .
 .
 .
 .
 fp = fopen("sample.txt" , "a");

 while(variable2)
 {

   fprintf(fp," %d \n", somevariable);

   usleep(20 * 1000);

 }

 fclose(fp);
}
```

Is it suitable to use usleep function achieve 20 milliseconds time interval or should I use some other methods like Timer.?
Is this usleep is accurate enough ? Does this sleep function any way affect the main thread ?

Comment: At least you can get current time with `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime` and to sleep only the time missing to the next activity.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races 4 Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the
other one reads or modifies the same memory location. 25 The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in
different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the
other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.* TL;DR: `sleep()` is not synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using of `sleep()` family often results in non-precise timing, especially when process has many CPU-consuming threads and required intervals are relatively small, like 20ms. So you shouldn't assume that `*sleep()` call blocks execution exactly to specified time. For described above situation actual sleep duration may be even twice or more greater than specified (assuming that kernel is not real-time one). As result you should implement some kind of compensation logic, that adjusts sleep duration for subsequent calls.

More precise (but of course not ideal) approach is to use POSIX timers. See [timer_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html). The most precise timers are the ones that use `SIGEV_SIGNAL` or `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` notifications (latter is only on Linux systems). As signal number you can use one of the real-time signals (`SIGRTMIN` to `SIGRTMAX`), but be aware that pthread implementations often use few of these signals internally, so you should choose actual number carefully. And also doing something in signal handler context requires extra attention, because not every library function may be used safely here. You can find safe list [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

P.S. Also note that `select()` called with empty sets is a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond precision.

Answer (score 2):

> **Sleeping: sleep() and usleep()**
>
> Now, let me start with the easier timing calls. For delays of multiple seconds, your best bet is probably to use sleep(). For delays of at least tens of milliseconds (about 10 ms seems to be the minimum delay), usleep() should work. These functions give the CPU to other processes (``sleep''), so CPU time isn't wasted. See the manual pages sleep(3) and usleep(3) for details.
>
> For delays of under about 50 milliseconds (depending on the speed of your processor and machine, and the system load), giving up the CPU takes too much time, because the Linux scheduler (for the x86 architecture) usually takes at least about 10-30 milliseconds before it returns control to your process. Due to this, in small delays, usleep(3) usually delays somewhat more than the amount that you specify in the parameters, and at least about 10 ms.
>
> **nanosleep()**
>
> In the 2.0.x series of Linux kernels, there is a new system call, nanosleep() (see the nanosleep(2) manual page), that allows you to sleep or delay for short times (a few microseconds or more).
>
> For delays <= 2 ms, if (and only if) your process is set to soft real time scheduling (using sched_setscheduler()), nanosleep() uses a busy loop; otherwise it sleeps, just like usleep().
>
> The busy loop uses udelay() (an internal kernel function used by many kernel drivers), and the length of the loop is calculated using the BogoMips value (the speed of this kind of busy loop is one of the things that BogoMips measures accurately). See /usr/include/asm/delay.h) for details on how it works.

Source: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IO-Port-Programming-4.html

Try use `nanosleep()` instead `usleep(`), it should be more accurately for 20ms interval.